# Adobe Lightroom - How to change metadata to make sorting in folders work?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, adobe

When i am importing all my photos to lightroom i want to sort my 2000 pictures in folders by date. But i have two big issues.

I only want folders per YEAR, not sub folders per month etc. Cant seem to import with only a YEAR folder. How can i do this?

Also when importing all my photos (10 years back in time), some are wrong by date. For example pictures on my kid when he was newborn are ending up in the 2014 year folder, how can i manually change the dates so they are being sorted correctly?

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, please refer to my [answer to this post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/48198/26144). It describes in Detail how you can customize the Folder Structure Lightroom creates on import.

To your second question: You need to manually select the pictures you want to edit, and then go to the Menu "Metadata > Edit Capture time"

Comment: Thanks, for number 2. Does that mean i need first to import all photos, do date changes on those needed. Then re-import all to have them automatically sorted in the correct folders?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. I'm not aware of any function to move those files around without re-importing them...

Answer (score 2):

To avoid a re-import. Once the metadata for the capture time is correct you should be able to go into your library module and sort by date... Getting your pictures in the right folder is simple as selecting the photos from one year and dropping them into the correct year in your folder hierarchy.